# Problems while working with Webdriver on HTML 5 and ExtJs

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an application which is developed in **ExtJs** and is a **HTML 5** type.

I an confronting a problem while interacting with button clicks and selecting drop down elements where only one option is present in the DD list.

Is this a problem with my **Webdriver Code**
Is this a problem with **Eclipse (By Kepler)**
Or is this a problem of **HTML 5** or **ExtJs**

Comment: To know the problem, we need the exact error message you are seeing.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen1345")).click();
    try {
      assertEquals("IT", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='boundlist-1134-listEl']/ul/li")).getText());
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='boundlist-1134-listEl']/ul/li")).click();`

Answer (score 1):

If `driver.findElement(By.something).click();` is not working for you you cant try click through java script:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script, element);
```

**Example:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("MainButton"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5, at the time of writing, is not fully supported with Selenium IDE. A good
example of this is elements that have the **contentEditable=true** attribute. If
you want to see this, you can use the type command to type something into the
html5div element. The test will tell you that it has completed the command but
the UI will not have changed